# does TTStyledText textFromXHTML not support the underline tags?

Tags: three20

Does TTStyledText textFromXHTML not support the underline tags?

I note for the the following code the bold'ing works, however the underline portion doesn't seem to?

```
NSString* htmlTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UnderlinedBoldNormal", we.title]; 
self.ttTitlelabel.text = [TTStyledText textFromXH`TML:htmlTitle];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope I don't think so.  The amount of formatting that `TTStyledText` supports is pretty limited

Comment: so it seems inclusion of the whole three20 package in my app just to get bolding/underlining support for text labels is probably not a good idea then?

Comment: three20 does allow you to only import the UI subpackage, so that may be what you want to do so you don't have to grab everything.  still pretty sizable probably

Answer (score 1):

There is no native support for underlined or strikethrough fonts on iOS. However you can overcome this by drawing your own line. A style could be created in your stylesheet:

```
- (TTStyle*)underlineStyle
{
  //custom TTStyle implementation
}
```

You could then get underlined text by:

```
NSString* htmlTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<span class=\"underlineStyle\">%@</span>", we.title]; 
self.ttTitlelabel.text = [TTStyledText textFromXHTML:htmlTitle];
```